# How to autocomplete Combobox in Web Browser?

Tags: vb.net

The combobox I am trying to autocomplete is **Select a category** from the following link : https://www.youtube.com/create_channel?action_create_new_channel_redirect=1 (you have to be logged in with your youtube account)

I got how to autofill the textbox (name your channel) using this code :

> WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PlusPageName").SetAttribute("Value", "Example")

I figured something like this but its not working

> WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PlusPageCategory").RaiseEvent()

Could someone help me please?

Comment: I figured something like this but its not working

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PlusPageCategory").RaiseEvent()

Comment: Please show your (full or at least a working example of your) code that you have so far and elaborate a bit more on your question (be more descriptive, what is wrong, what have you expected), so that someone can help you. With two lines of code it is very difficult to spot the problem.

Comment: Why i should add more code if that is the whole code i have. I guess someone who knows what I am talking about would know, i gave alot of details about what I am trying to code

Comment: So you want to convince me, that you have a VB.NET project consisting of one line only? About the *someone who knows* - if it was so easy to deduce problems from one sentence only, then life would be a lot more easier: go to a restaurant, say you want to eat and if you are lucky, you will get **exactly** what you wanted to order, but 99% of the time it will not happen and you need to explain in **detail** and using many words exactly what you want. Same rules [apply here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class used for the combo box value is `goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption`.

To set the value of this, you would have to use the following code:

```
For Each el As Element In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    If el.GetAttribute("classname").ToString = "goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" Then
        el.InnerText = "Company, Institution or Organization" 'or whatever value
    End If
Next
```

Hope this helped,

Rodit

Comment: Hey, it's working. Thank you very much! but there is a little mistake, it has to be "HtmlElement" instead of "Element" in your code. Thanks ;)

Comment: Hey i just got a problem, the combobox is autocompleting but when i click "Done" button(on that youtube form) manually or automatically in my web-browser the combobox returns again to "Select a category" with "You can't leave this empty" message, like the combobox is not completing, what is wrong ?